# Calculating IDAT checksums in python

Tags: python, png, zlib, crc32

I've been wracking my brains and the net as to why this doesn't work. I'm trying to write some code to verify IDAT checksums, and testing as I go with a sample good image. My code is:

```
import binascii
import zlib

filename="sample.png";
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    data=f.read()

index=data.find("IDAT");
print index;

idat=data[index:index+0x200+4]
print "IDAT: "+binascii.hexlify(idat)

crc=data[index+0x200+4:index+0x200+8]
print "CRC: "+binascii.hexlify(crc)

ccrc=zlib.crc32(idat)
print"Calculated CRC: "+hex(ccrc)
```

The output it gives is:

```
python crc.py
190
IDAT: 494441546881edd6cd6...........<snip>
CRC: ce1f4dd7
Calculated CRC: -0x31e0b229
```

The checksum is being read from the right location. The IDAT header and data is being checksummed. I've verified with other tools that the checksum read from the file is correct. From my research, zlib's default settings should give the right output with CRC32.

What is missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Wow I'm an idiot! I checked this earlier when I had something wrong then thought I had already checked it in this case. I just needed to & it with 0xffffffff due to integer signing.